# Play different audio by clicking on class element

Tags: javascript

after many hours looking for a solution by myself, I'm asking for your help.

I'd like to play audio by clicking on an img and this is how I organised my code in HTML, audio will be different for each class : a_ru.mp3, b_ru.mp3 etc.

```
    <span class="btn-audio-lexique">
        <audio src="http://localhost/linguami-offline/fr/mp3/a_ru.mp3"></audio>
        <img src="http://localhost/linguami-offline/img/circled-play.png">
    </span>

    <span class="btn-audio-lexique">
        <audio src="http://localhost/linguami-offline/fr/mp3/b_ru.mp3"></audio>
        <img src="http://localhost/linguami-offline/img/circled-play.png">
    </span>
```

JS part which is unfortunately not workings looks like that

```
    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-audio-lexique");

function playSound() {
    var audio = classname.firstElementChild;
    audio.play();
};

Array.from(classname).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', playSound);
});
```

I also tried with a for loop

```
    for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', playSound);
}
```

console returns me a "audio is undefined error".

I would like to avoid creating a different id for all the audio in my page.

does anyone have an idea how should I organise my code for this works?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `var audio = event.currentTarget.firstElementChild;`

Comment: This worked for me : function playSound(e) {
 var audio = e.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
 audio.play();
};

Thanks for the tip @Slai !

I tried with e.target but it was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few mistakes in your code:

I. Do not add event listener to each action element. It's bad for performance reasons. You should add event listener to some common parent element, which holds all the children buttons.

```
document.querySelector('.myAwesomeContainer').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  var target = e.target;

  if (target && target.classList.contains('btn-audio-lexique')) {
      var audio = target.firstElementChild;
      // var audio = target.querySelector('audio');

      if (audio) {
        audio.play();
      }
  }
});
```

II. You don't necessarily need to mess up with audio elements. You can use AudioAPI and play sounds like:

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
audio.play();
```

III. DO NOT use `<span>`, `<div>` or any HTML tag as clickable stuff except `<button>`, `<a>` Because you're destroing semantic markup and reducing accessability of you're application to the ground.

---

The actual reason of error in your current code, is hidden in that row:

```
var audio = classname.firstElementChild;
```

You're trying to get `audio` element not from the actual `SPAN` which user clicked, but from the array-like object of all your spans. Because `classname` is a LIST of all spans. What can you do in that situation? Just add `event` param to your `playSound` function. Because `addEventListener` will pass that param when event will be triggered:

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-audio-lexique");

function playSound(e) {
    // Get actual clicked element
    var target = e.target;
    var audio = target.firstElementChild;
    if (audio) {
        audio.play();
    }

};

Array.from(classname).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', playSound);
});
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you're learning JS, but also you need to do your job, may be it will be better to use jQuery? It will help you with all that listeners and events stuff. But academically, it's better to do everything on the native JS of course.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to understand how does JS vanilla work before to switch on any library, you got it.